# How to include JQuery/Bootstrap in PhoneGap Build?

Tags: jquery, html, phonegap-build, phonegap

I am trying to make an app with PhoneGap Build. I link to my index.html file on GitHub, which includes links in the head to a JQuery cdn, as well as some other JS resources. The problem is when I build the app and try to test it, JQuery doesn't work and neither do the other resources. Where in my HTML file should I include the links to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link to them as you are, but you need to whitelist the urls for it to work in the app.

Or you can DL and include the actual files and include them in your app. That's what I did.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.